# USB HUB not responding

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design, microchip, usb-hub

In my design I am using a **USB2517i USB 2.0 Hi-Speed 7-Port Hub Controller** and I am following the microchip reference schematic with the default settings.

I am trying to interface the USB hub with imx6q(NXP) processor board that running Yocto 4.15 kernel. The thing is the processor board is not recognizing the USB hub.

The block diagram representation is shown below.[image] also i am enclosing our schematic design.[Schematic for USB HUB](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q6f445ejoz5wibn/USB%20Hub.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: Have you tried using the hub with another host?

Comment: Do you have those "provisions to isolate" configured correctly?

Comment: Yes i configured correctly

Comment: Bruce i connected upstream usb connection to the windows pc it shows that device descriptor error i can't understand what i missed??

Comment: The double-connection to host processor doesn't make sense. The processor can't be both host and device simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

We found out the issue, the crystal placement was wrong on usb hub. We rectified it.
 
The crystal pin no: 1 was confusing and ended up in trouble.
 
Thanks for the support !!!